# Updating table with inner join and having in MySQL

Tags: mysql, having

I have this selection query in MySQL:

```
select r.list_id
from vicidial_list as r
inner join vicidial_log as p
on r.phone_number=p.phone_number
where p.user='vdad' and p.list_id='30000' and p.status='na' and r.alt_phone is not null and r.alt_phone!=' ' and r.alt_phone!='' and r.phone_number is not null and r.phone_number!='' and r.phone_number!=' '
and r.alt_phone not in(
select k.phone_number from vicidial_list as k)
group by p.phone_number
having count(p.phone_number)>10
```

I want to `update` all `r.list_id`. How can I do? If I write this I get error:

```
update vicidial_list
set vicidial_list.list_id='12345'
where vicidial_list.list_id in
(
   select r.list_id
    from vicidial_list as r
    inner join vicidial_log as p
    on r.phone_number=p.phone_number
    where p.user='vdad' and p.list_id='30000' and p.status='na' and r.alt_phone is not null and r.alt_phone!=' ' and r.alt_phone!='' and r.phone_number is not null and r.phone_number!='' and r.phone_number!=' '
    and r.alt_phone not in(
    select k.phone_number from vicidial_list as k)
    group by p.phone_number
    having count(p.phone_number)>10
)
```

The error is: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'vicidial_list' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Paste the error message buddy !

Comment: Wrap the query of the `WHERE` clause in a subquery and select `list_id` from this subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is checked for every row while updating. Since a previous row might have changed and this might have influenced the result of the subquery in the `WHERE` clause, this is not allowed. Put your subquery in the `FROM` clause instead and join to it.

```
update vicidial_list
join 
(
   select r.list_id
    from vicidial_list as r
    inner join vicidial_log as p
    on r.phone_number=p.phone_number
    where p.user='vdad' and p.list_id='30000' and p.status='na' and r.alt_phone is not null and r.alt_phone!=' ' and r.alt_phone!='' and r.phone_number is not null and r.phone_number!='' and r.phone_number!=' '
    and r.alt_phone not in(
    select k.phone_number from vicidial_list as k)
    group by p.phone_number
    having count(p.phone_number)>10
) sq ON sq.list_id = vicidial_list.list_id
set vicidial_list.list_id = '12345';
```